# Setting the height of a sliding div

Tags: jquery

How do I set the height to a vertically sliding div? I have used jQuery and here is the code for it:

When I say set the height, I mean so the div only slides say 1000px where it will stop sliding? The issue I have is that in smaller smaller screen sizes, the sliding div always wants to be shown, so on some pages it pushes the footer down, so the user can never see the footer!?

http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/psychometric-test.htm

Thanks.

210895

Comment: I think you forgot to add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi one possible solution can be to add automatic scrollbar:

CSS:

```css
#sidebar {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var topPadding = 15;
    var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
    sidebar.css('max-height', $(window).height() - 2*topPadding); // initialize max-height
    $(window).resize(function() {
        sidebar.css('max-height', $(window).height() - 2*topPadding);
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() + topPadding
        });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Prjw3/)

Javascript for your page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var topPadding = 15;
        var crfoffset = $("div.contentRightFull").offset().top;
        var winoffset = $(window).scrollTop();
        var stioffset = $("#stickymojo").height() - $('#sidebar').height();
        var mtop = Math.max(0, winoffset-crfoffset);
        if (mtop>stioffset) { mtop = stioffset; }
        $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
            marginTop: mtop + topPadding
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hi Stano, I have done this but I still have the same problem. I have uploaded the page here. Is there anything I am doing wrong, or any of the code I needed to edit? Thanks in advance! http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/psychometric-test.htm

Comment: Hi Stano, thank you, I am still getting the same issue though, it still pushes the footer down, do I need to set a max height somewhere? http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/psychometric-test.htm. Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean it needs to be shrinked further?

Comment: Oh I am sorry it was only my inattention, I was looking at old page, now your page is updated and ok. Have a nice day :-)